# How to get gray background to top to bottom?

Tags: tables, macros, spacing, graphics, formatting

I really like this CV (the first screenshot) and the closest I have been able to find is [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-template/kmkzxwnmvmqq) (the second screenshot). The complete source code is [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zxyfqbwpfbfz).

If I delete the first `tcolorbox` section and in `preamble.tex` set

```
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=0mm,
  right=7mm,
  bottom=0mm,
  top=0mm
}
```

the the grey fills to the left and bottom, but for some reason not the top.

**Question**

Can someone figure what is needed to get the grey to go all the way to the top of the paper like in the first screenshot?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add code here don't use external links, especially not links that are not world readable

Comment: Doesn't this template be closest to your first screenshoot? https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv (it's slightly modified from this code: https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex). However, I have provided a solution with your other template.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry about that. Is there a recommended way to include 2-3 tex files? They are relatively long for produce this CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (code for `preamble.tex` and `macros.tex` is from the template here: https://www.overleaf.com/project/63dada0a427cf681232e7ed8, but I copy the content of these files below, so my answer is not linked to an external link).

The trick is to reverse the order of the minipages (first the minipage with Side panel, and add the image in this side panel, and then the minipage with the main panel which contain a tcolorbox with the name and contact info, and below Profile, Work experience etc.).

```latex
\input{setup/preamble.tex}
\input{setup/macros.tex}

\begin{document}

    %%% Sections %%%

    \tcbset{colframe=white,colback=white,arc=0mm, height=\textheight}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \vspace*{-1em}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth} % Side Panel (e.g. Skills, Links, Languages, etc.)
            \begin{tcolorbox}[height=\textheight, grow to left by=0.6cm,colback=backdrop,colframe=backdrop,arc=0mm]

                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} % Picture
                
                % Skills, the skill level is drawn as bars, input: skill name and an array starting from 0 and ending before 4
                \subsection*{Skills}
                    \skill{Python}{0, 1, 2, 3}
                    \skill{Git}{0, 1, 2}
                    \skill{Linux}{0, 1, 2, 3}
                    \skill{Java}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
                    \skill{C++}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
                    \skill{LaTeX}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

                \subsection*{Languages}
                    \lan{English}{0, 1, 2, 3}
                    \lan{Spanish}{0, 1, 2, 3}
                    \lan{Danish}{0, 1, 2, 3}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth} % Main Panel (e.g. Education, Work Experience)
            \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=0.75cm,height=1.00\textheight,colframe=white,colback=white]

    %%% TItle %%%

    \vspace*{-0.75em}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=title,colback=title,arc=0mm]

        \begin{minipage}{1.00\textwidth} % Name and Contact Info
            \name{John Doe}{Carpe Diem} % Name and Profession
            \vspace{2em}
            \email{john.doe@mail.com} $\cdot$
            \phone{+31 555 555 555} \par \vspace{0.5em}
            \address{London, England} $\cdot$
            \github{https://github.com/}{JohnDoe}
        \end{minipage}
        
    \end{tcolorbox}


                % Profile Section
                \section*{Profile}
                    \lipsum[20]

                % Work Experience
                \section*{Work Experience}
                    \work{Mechanical Engineer}{Sep 2026 - Oct 2028}{Some Company}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla ac nisl. Nullam urna nulla, ullamcorper in, interdum sit amet, gravida ut, risus.}

                % Education
                \section*{Education}
                    \education{MSc in Mechanical Engineering}{Sep 2020 - Oct 2024}{Stanford University}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla ac nisl. Nullam urna nulla, ullamcorper in, interdum sit amet, gravida ut, risus.} \vspace{2em}
                    \education{BSc in Electrical Engineering}{Sep 2018 - Oct 2020}{Stanford University}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla ac nisl. Nullam urna nulla, ullamcorper in, interdum sit amet, gravida ut, risus.}

                % Publications
                \section*{Publications}
                    \pub{SplitPotato: A novel approach towards splitting potato chromosomes}{2 June 2022}{Stanford University}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla ac nisl. Nullam urna nulla, ullamcorper in, interdum sit amet, gravida ut, risus.}{https://scholar.google.com/}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{document}
```

You will get:

[image]

### Edit

Adding content of `preamble.tex` and `macros.tex` so the answer in not linked to an external source.

#### preamble.tex

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% IMPORTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt,onesize,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Formatting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} % Margins
\usepackage{sectsty} % Custom Sections

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Font %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Graphics %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{fontawesome5} % Icons
\usepackage{graphicx} % Images
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % Color Box
\usepackage{xcolor} % Colors
\usepackage{tikz} % For Drawing Shapes
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Miscelanous %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{lipsum} % Lorem Ipsum
\usepackage{hyperref} % For Hyperlinks

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Colors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\definecolor{title}{HTML}{4bfbba} % Color of the title
\definecolor{backdrop}{HTML}{f2f2f2} % Color of the side column
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{b8b8b8} % Color for the skill bars

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Section Format %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\sectionfont{                     
    \LARGE % Font size
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-8pt}{1pt} % Rule under Section name
}

\subsectionfont{
    \large % Font size
    \fontfamily{phv}\selectfont % Font family
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-8pt}{1pt} % Rule under Subsection name
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Margins and Headers %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=7mm,
  right=7mm,
  bottom=10mm,
  top=10mm
}

\pagestyle{empty} % Empty Headers
```

#### macros.tex

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MACROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Link With an Icon %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\link}[1]{
    \href{#1}{\faIcon{link}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Name Template %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\name}[2]{
    % Name
    \Huge % Font size
    \raggedright \textbf{#1} \par

    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    
    % Profession
    \Large % Font size
    \raggedright #2 \par
    \normalsize \normalfont
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Contact Details %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\info}[2]{
    \faIcon{#2} \hspace{0.2em} #1
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Email %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\email}[1]{
    \info{#1}{envelope}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Phone Number %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{
    \info{#1}{mobile-alt}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Address %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\address}[1]{
    \info{#1}{map-marker-alt}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% GitHub %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\github}[2]{
    \info{\href{#1}{\underline{#2}}}{github}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LinkedIn %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{
    \info{\href{#1}{\underline{#2}}}{linkedin}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Website %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\website}[1]{
    \info{#1}{link}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Draw Skill Bars %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\drawskillbars}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Draw 5 gray bars
        \foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}{
            \fill[lightgray] (\i * 0.7 + 0.2 *\i,0) rectangle (0.7 + \i * 0.7 + \i * 0.2,0.1);
        }
        
        % Draw number of black bars depending on the skill level
        \foreach \i in {#1}{
            \fill[black] (\i * 0.7 + 0.2 *\i,0) rectangle (0.7 + \i * 0.7 + \i * 0.2,0.1);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture} \par
}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Skills %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\skill}[2]{
    % Name of the skill
    \large
    \noindent \hangafter=0
    \textmd{#1}
    \normalsize \par 
    % Skill bars
    \drawskillbars{#2}
    \vspace{1.5em}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Language %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\lan}[2]{
    % Name of the language
    \large
    \noindent \hangafter=0
    \textmd{#1}
    % Knowledge level
    \drawskillbars{#2}
    \vspace{1em}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Education %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\education}[4]{
    % Name of the studies
    \noindent \large \parbox{.7\linewidth}{\textbf{#1}}
    % Duration in a Box
    \hfill \scriptsize
    \tcbox[enhanced,box align=base,nobeforeafter,colback=title,colframe=title,size=fbox,arc=0mm]{\textbf{#2}} \par
    \vspace{0.3em}
    % School Name 
    \large
    \noindent \color{title} \parbox{.7\linewidth}{\textsl{#3}} \par
    % Description
    \normalsize \color{black}
    \vspace*{0.3em}
    \small #4 
    \normalsize \par
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Work Experience %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\work}[4]{
    % Name of the Job
    \noindent \large \parbox{.7\linewidth}{\textbf{#1}}
    % Duration in a Box 
    \hfill \scriptsize
    \tcbox[enhanced,box align=base,nobeforeafter,colback=title,colframe=title,size=fbox,arc=0mm]{\textbf{#2}} \par
    \vspace{0.3em}
    % Name of the Employer
    \noindent \large \color{title} \parbox{.7\linewidth}{\textsl{#3}} \par
    % Description of the job
    \vspace*{0.3em} \color{black}
    \small #4 
    \normalsize \par
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Publications %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\pub}[5]{
    % Title
    \noindent \large \parbox{.7\linewidth}{\textbf{#1} \link{#5}}
    % Publication Date
    \hfill \scriptsize
    \tcbox[enhanced,box align=base,nobeforeafter,colback=title,colframe=title,size=fbox,arc=0mm]{\textbf{#2}} \par
    \vspace{0.3em}
    % Institution
    \large
    \noindent \color{title} \parbox{.7\linewidth}{\textsl{#3}} \par
    % Description
    \vspace*{0.3em} \color{black}
    \small \textit{#4} \par
    \normalsize \par 
}
```

Comment: When I click on your link I get to a copy of unmodified code. If I open it in Incognito mode, then I get permission denied. When I try to implement your changes is get this https://www.overleaf.com/4541248566vpyhkhpfrvqq . I can't get the right column to be link yours. Can you take a look what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting I updated my answer so you don't have to click on a external source. You need to create a new project with all the above codes. As the main code begins with `\input{setup/preamble.tex}` you need to create a "setup" folder in your project, and then add files named "preamble.tex" and "macros.tex". Or simply go to https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-template/kmkzxwnmvmqq, click on "Open as Template", and replace the main code (main.tex) with mine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did see that the code block had scrollers. Now it works perfectly =) Thanks =)